# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity Only Importing First Row of XML file

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an XML file that I am importing into a SQL table using an Azure pipeline data copy activity.  The file imports fine, but only imports the very first row into the SQL table.  It does not import all the records

[XML file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M27lR.png)

Mapping as follows:

[Copy Activity Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vjg7.png)

I have done some research and according to one forum, the mapping syntax should be changed.
Currently the mapping is

$['queues']['queue'][0]['Field'][0]['*value*']

It is suggested the the mappings are changed to reference the actual field name.

$['queues']['queue'][0]['@queue_date'][0]['*value*']

This does not rectify the issue. Only the first record in the XML file imports.